# How to bind a Kendo Grid on a button click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have to bind a kendo grid on button click and got the example in another SO question: [Kendo Grid - Bind Data After Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261998/kendo-grid-bind-data-after-search) , but this is not working for me. My controller action is returning the json object but that object is not getting mapped to my grid.

The following is the same code presented in the other question:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Project.Data.Entity.SearchResult>()
   .Name("ClaimantSearch") 
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource 
        .Ajax() 
    //.Read(read => read.Action("Search", "Claimant")) ) 
   .Columns(columns => 
   { 
    columns.Bound(x => x.Name); 
    columns.Bound(x => x.Authorized); 
    columns.Bound(x => x.CompanyName); 
    columns.Bound(x => x.Address); 
    }) 
   .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
)
```

Javascript:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    alert('a');
    $.ajax({
        data: '@Url.Action("Search", "Claimant")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var grid = $('#Claimant').getKendoGrid();
            grid.dataSource.data(result);
            grid.refresh();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you check console for errors?

Comment: Would be great if you can share the code.

Comment: Can you post code where you're binding your grid?

Comment: @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Project.Data.Entity.SearchResult>()
 .Name("ClaimantSearch")
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
  .Ajax()
  //.Read(read => read.Action("Search", "Claimant"))
  )
  .Columns(columns =>
 {
  columns.Bound(x => x.Name);
  columns.Bound(x => x.Authorized);
  columns.Bound(x => x.CompanyName);
  columns.Bound(x => x.Address);
    
 })
 .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
   
 )

Comment: $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
 alert('a');
 $.ajax({
  data: '@Url.Action("Search", "Claimant")',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  data: "",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
   alert(data);
   var grid = $('#Claimant').getKendoGrid(); 
   grid.dataSource.data(result);
   grid.refresh();
  }
 });
return false;
});

Comment: If on load of page i am calling the action the data is displayed but on click of button I am not able to. on load i am using  ".Read(read => read.Action("Search", "Claimant"))" to display the grid data.

Comment: Are you able to debug the "Search" Action on button click?

Comment: Ya and it is returning data also but that data I am not able to get that into grid

Answer (score 2):

You can add **.AutoBind(false)**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Project.Data.Entity.SearchResult>()
  .Name("ClaimantSearch") 
  .AutoBind(false)
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource 
  .Ajax() 
  .Read(read => read.Action("Search", "Claimant")) ) 
  .Columns(columns => 
{ 
 columns.Bound(x => x.Name); 
 columns.Bound(x => x.Authorized); 
 columns.Bound(x => x.CompanyName); 
 columns.Bound(x => x.Address); 
}) 
.Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
)

<input type="button" value="Generate" id="btnGenerate" />
```

You can add **$("#ClaimantSearch").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();** in Jquery button click event

```
<script>
$('#btnGenerate').click(function () {
    $("#ClaimantSearch").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting .AutoBind(false) option comes with the Kendo grid.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your success callback with this:

```
success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
    var grid = $('#Claimant').getKendoGrid();
    grid.dataSource.data(result);
    grid.refresh();
}
```

The problem was simply that you renamed the function argument to `data` but you were still trying to bind `result`. Change it back to `result` and it should work.

Also, I noticed you have two `data` attributes in your ajax call, might want to remove the blank one.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass parameter from View to Controller, .Data("additionalInfo") is added to the .Read property of grid's .DataSource

**ASP.NET MVC Solution**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Your_Model>()
    .Name("grd_yourGrid")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.modelAttribute).Width(300);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 500px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes((new int[] { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200 }).ToList())
        .ButtonCount(15))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
           .Ajax().ServerOperation(false)
           .Read(read => read.Action("MyActionName", "MyController").Data("additionalInfo"))
        .PageSize(100)
    ))
```

Javascript:

```
 <script>

        $('#btn_yourButtonName').click(function () {

            $("#grd_yourGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

            return false; // WITHOUT THIS GRID WILL NOT BE FILLED
        });


        function additionalInfo() {
            return {
                startRange: $("#inputValueOne").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value(),
                endRange: $("#inputValueTwo").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value()
            }
        }
</script>
```

Controller (MyController):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionName([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string startRange, string endRange){}
```